# Analysing data set with pandas

Tags: pandas

I am a beginner in the data science field. I am trying to do some aggregation on the data but not sure how to code it.
I have the following data frame. I need to udnerstand how i can calculate the total no of jobs done by a driver (Driver ID is unique)

[image]
 [image]

```
df = data.groupby(['dr_status','No_of_jobs']).size()
```

How to tweak  so i can see an output like the following?

```
Diver_ID -  Total_Jobs

53028  - 45

53051  - 20
```

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post.

The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Not a `scikit-learn`-related question - I am changing the title & tag to `pandas` - pls confirm that you are using pandas indeed...

Comment: yes this is an operation related to pandas. thanks for your suggestion.@ desertnaut

Comment: would it not be `df.groupby('Driver_Id')['No_of_Jobs'].sum()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum` No_of_jobs and `groupby` driver id should do the job

```
data.groupby('Driver_Id')['No_of_jobs'].sum()
```

another option is `pivot_table` with `aggfunc=['count']` :

```
df.pivot_table(values=['No_of_jobs'],index='Driver_Id',aggfunc=['count'])
```